# Parse a nested dynamic module using Gson

Tags: java, gson

I have a JSON that looks more or less like this:

```
{
  "modules": {
    "someExistingModule": {
      "name": "pug",
      ...
    },

    "randomExistingModule": {
      "type": "cat",
      ...
    },

    "myNewModule": {   // <----- I care about this module. Note that this is NOT an array
      "modules": {
        "img1": {
          "type": "image",
          "url": "https://some/random/image,
          "altText": "Some image description
        },
        "img2": {
          "type": "image",
          "url": "https://some/random/image,
          "altText": "Some image description
        },
        "img3": {
          "type": "image",
          "url": "https://some/random/image,
          "altText": "Some image description
        },
        "txt1": {           // <------ Updated JSON
          "type": "text",
          "content": "Hello world 1"
        },
        "txt2": {
          "type": "text",
          "content": "Hello world 2"
        },
        ...
      }
    }
```

Inside `myModule` there can be `N` number of `imgN` objects and `txtN`. I need to parse this dynamically.

My current Response class looks like this:

```
public class MyModuleResponse extends SomeResponseClass
{
  @Override
    public void parse(InputStream data)
    {
        T responseBody = readJsonStream(data, MyModuleResponseBody.class());
        MyModuleDataParser.parse(responseBody);
    }
```

`MyModuleDataParser.java`

```
...
public static MyModuleDataParser parse(@Nullable MyModuleResponseBody body)
{
  parseSomeExistingModule();

  parseRandomExistingModule();

  parseMyNewModule(); // <--- This is the new module I'm trying to parse. Currently, this method is empty.

}
```

`MyModuleResponseBody.java`

```
public class MyModuleResponseBody
{
  public Modules modules;

  public static class Modules
  {
    SomeExistingModule someExistingModule;
    RandomExistingModule randomExistingModule;
    MyNewModule myNewModule; // <----- My new module
  }

  public static class SomeExistingModule
  {
    String name;
    ...
  }

  public static class RandomExistingModule
  {
    String type;
    ...
  }

  public static class MyNewModule
    {
        public ??? modules;   // <--- Trying to define the Type here. Something like List<MyImageModule>. But, it won't work
    }
```

`MyImageModule.java`

```
public class MyImageModule extends Module // <---- Update: This class now extends a generic Module class
{
  private String url;
  private String altText;
}
```

`MyTextModule.java`  <---- New Module

```
public class MyTextModule extends Module    // New class
{
  private String content;
}
```

`Module.java`

```
public class Module  // <----- New parent class
{
  protected String type;
}
```

How do I create a list of `MyImageModule` from `myNewModule`? I believe I need to use some kind of `TypeAdapter` from Gson library. But, I'm not familiar how to do this inside an existing response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Map<String, MyImageModule>`, in fact, a `hashmap` to solve the issue of `non-list modules` object in the json.

```
public static class MyNewModule {
    public Map<String, MyImageModule> modules; // initialize as a hashmap
}
```

Comment: That works! However, let's the inner `modules` can have `MyImageModule` and `MyTextModule`. Both of these modules extend from, say, `Module`. How would i define this Map?

Comment: You can map them to `Map<String, Object>` and then cast the object to the relevant one during other operation, say getting through `keys` and you know what key is for image and what for text inside the `modues` json.

Comment: Should I map them to `Map<String,Object>` or can I use `Map<String,Module>`? I tried the latter and seems to hold only the Key. The Value was set to `null`. I have updated my question description with new classes and JSON

Comment: No, you should map them to `Map<String,Object>` and do a `get(key)` on it and cast it to the desired class